# Issues uploading a video file into Amazon S3 using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

I have develop a ASP.NET (C#) application to store the images and videos into Amazon S3. Images are being uploaded fine but when i try to upload videos it saves as an image format in Amazon S3.

Does anyone know what the issue is or how to I can upload videos?

```
private void Amzon(string imageName,string imgcontenttype,int imglength,byte[] fileData)
{
    AmazonS3 myS3 = new AmazonS3();
    DateTime myTime = DateTime.Now;

    // Create a signature for this operation
    string strMySignature = S3Helper.GetSignature(mySecretAccessKeyId, "PutObjectInline", myTime);

    // Create a new Access grant for anonymous users.
    Grant myGrant = new Grant();
    Grant[] myGrants = new Grant[1];

    // Setup Access control, allow Read access to all
    Group myGroup = new Group();
    myGroup.URI = "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers";
    myGrant.Grantee = myGroup;
    myGrant.Permission = Permission.READ;
    myGrants[0] = myGrant;
    string key = imageName;
    // Setup some metadata to indicate the content type
    MetadataEntry myContentType = new MetadataEntry();
    myContentType.Name = "ContentType";
    myContentType.Value = imgcontenttype;

    MetadataEntry[] myMetaData = new MetadataEntry[1];
    myMetaData[0] = myContentType;

    // Finally upload the object
    PutObjectResult myResult = myS3.PutObjectInline(
        bucketname,
        key,
        myMetaData,
        fileData,
        imglength,
        myGrants,
        StorageClass.STANDARD,
        true,
        myAWSAccessKeyId,
        S3Helper.GetTimeStamp(myTime),
        true,
        strMySignature, null
        );

    // Print out the results.
    if (myResult != null)
    {
        cn.Open();
        Url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/" + bucketname + "/" + key;
        string Query = "Insert into S3Image(ImageName,ImageUrl)Values('" + key + "','" + Url + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        //MyPrint("ETag: " + myResult.ETag);
        MyPrint("<img src=https://s3.amazonaws.com/" + bucketname + "/" + key);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what formats of video are you trying to upload? What is the extension of the videos? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Thank you for giving Response, i have try .mp4 formate files to upload

Comment: Are you able to show us some code? It's a bit hard to work out what the issue could be if without that.

Comment: Hi i have paste my code in my above Question Please fin that code ..

Comment: Hi any idea for this issue please tell me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of code to get up and running with Amazon's web service. I think this part of code is what you need, you might not be setting the right content type:

```
// Setup some metadata to indicate the content type 
        MetadataEntry myContentType = new MetadataEntry();
        myContentType.Name = "ContentType";
        myContentType.Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
```

Here's the full code: Enjoy.

```
`private const string accessKeyId = "REMOVED";
    private const string secretAccessKey = "REMOVED";
    private static DateTime GetTimeStamp(DateTime myTime)
    {
        DateTime myUniversalTime = myTime.ToUniversalTime();
        DateTime myNewTime = new DateTime(myUniversalTime.Year,
        myUniversalTime.Month, myUniversalTime.Day,
        myUniversalTime.Hour, myUniversalTime.Minute,
        myUniversalTime.Second, myUniversalTime.Millisecond);

        return myNewTime;
    }
    private static string GetSignature(string secretAccessKey, string strOperation, DateTime myTime)
    {
        Encoding myEncoding = new UTF8Encoding();

        // Create the source string which is used to create the digest
        string mySource = "AmazonS3" + strOperation + FormatTimeStamp(myTime);

        // Create a new Cryptography class using the 
        // Secret Access Key as the key
        HMACSHA1 myCrypto = new HMACSHA1(myEncoding.GetBytes(secretAccessKey));

        // Convert the source string to an array of bytes
        char[] mySourceArray = mySource.ToCharArray();
        // Convert the source to a UTF8 encoded array of bytes
        byte[] myUTF8Bytes = myEncoding.GetBytes(mySourceArray);
        // Calculate the digest 
        byte[] strDigest = myCrypto.ComputeHash(myUTF8Bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(strDigest);
    }
    private static string FormatTimeStamp(DateTime myTime)
    {
        DateTime myUniversalTime = myTime.ToUniversalTime();
        return myUniversalTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss.fff\\Z", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Upload Images.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">Ex. FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType</param>
    /// <param name="b">Ex. FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName</param>
    /// <param name="c">Ex. FileUpload1.FileBytes</param>
    /// <param name="d">Ex. FileUpload1.FileBytes.Length</param>
    /// <param name="id">The ID for this Product Group</param>
    public void UploadImage_ProductGroup(string a, string b, byte[] c, long d, int id)
    {
        AmazonS3 myS3 = new AmazonS3();
        DateTime myTime = DateTime.Now;

        // Create a signature for this operation
        string strMySignature = GetSignature(
        secretAccessKey,
        "PutObjectInline",
        myTime);

        // Create a new Access grant for anonymous users.
        Grant myGrant = new Grant();
        Grant[] myGrants = new Grant[1];

        // Setup Access control, allow Read access to all
        Group myGroup = new Group();
        myGroup.URI = "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers";
        myGrant.Grantee = myGroup;
        myGrant.Permission = Permission.READ;
        myGrants[0] = myGrant;

        // Setup some metadata to indicate the content type 
        MetadataEntry myContentType = new MetadataEntry();
        myContentType.Name = "ContentType";
        myContentType.Value = a;

        MetadataEntry[] myMetaData = new MetadataEntry[1];
        myMetaData[0] = myContentType;

        //Format the file name to prepend thumbnail before the file extension.
      /*  int lastIndex = b.LastIndexOf('.');
        string fileName = b.Remove(lastIndex);
        string ext = b.Remove(0, lastIndex);
        string thumbPath = string.Format("images/public/{0}thumb{1}",fileName,ext);
        //Resize the thumbnail
        */



        // Finally upload the object
        PutObjectResult myResult = myS3.PutObjectInline(
            "mywebsite",
        "images/public/" + b,
            myMetaData,
            c,
            d,
            myGrants,
            StorageClass.STANDARD,
            true,
            accessKeyId,
            GetTimeStamp(myTime),
            true,
            strMySignature, null
        );`
```

Comment: Hi Nick Thank you for giving responce ,Can u post entire uploaad class.Then only i can find my Problem .. Above i have post my code what i did for uploading please see that code...

Comment: You have a variable called imgcontenttype, i'm not able to tell what content type you're actually passing to it.

Comment: I get the feeling this could be the case.

Comment: just i assign the content type to a variable which i get from upload file ..but u are assign directly like FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;

Comment: Hi it is working fine Thank you,But it accept only 1mb file.It doesn't accept more than that,how can i upload more than 1mb please help me...

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, Amazon has a few different ways to upload content. I believe this web method we are using is the SOAP client which only allows 1 or 2 MB. This is the link that I used to get my previous example working- it may tell you how to get a larger file uploaded: http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/